# How to import trained DNNClassifier using C_API

Tags: tensorflow, c-api

I have trained DNNClassifier using Python (conda tensorflow installation). The trained model needs to be used for evaluation using C_API. Is there a way to load both graph and weights of the trained model using C_API?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to load h5 and any data for C_API. Maybe some googling could help. I've found [this article](https://gist.github.com/asimshankar/7c9f8a9b04323e93bb217109da8c7ad2) to be helpful.

And for DNNClassifier on C_API I think you should Implement it manually using pure Tensor Array on C_API. cmiimw